# Are php's zlib_encode() and zlib_decode not opposite?

Tags: php, encoding, decode, zlib

I wrote a function (in php) that decodes some data (the data is first zlib-encoded and then base-64 encoded).

Now I want to make a function that reverses that action - but something strange happens while encoding the data. I had this string (this is after the base64 decode so this is only zlib-encoded):

```
xÚc22Ñ5±RÈM-ÉÈOÉLNÌQpdFZ6<€‘/`„¸Ž]œ(•šÁáÁôÀm%Âp,¦CÍ†êF5ÉGÄŽa:Ìl˜ndÓ‘C‹áœÈB6±¥Ä€ ¤¦¦¥¦$¥&%'¦¥df¤e¤g¤"#¡b¤c¤¡ÆÀ˜%&¯TÍ’ Ä¤'£Ç¤¤ Äà`•¢Ç §H  %=†=–%ô(`f“s0¨’c`)¥]
```

and when calling `zlib_encode(zlib_decode(base64_decode($data)))` on the original string, it outputs `NULL`. I've looked at [php's `zlib_encode` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.zlib-encode.php) and found that I needed to give the type of compression. Well, no luck with that either:

```
var_dump(zlib_encode(zlib_decode(base64_decode($data)),ZLIB_ENCODING_RAW));
var_dump(zlib_encode(zlib_decode(base64_decode($data)),ZLIB_ENCODING_GZIP));
var_dump(zlib_encode(zlib_decode(base64_decode($data)),ZLIB_ENCODING_DEFLATE));
```

returns

```
string(194) "c22Ñ5±RÈM-ÉÈOÉLNÌQpdFZ6<€Ÿ,Ðe×q¢‹s¡Ò@3!<˜¸­DŽÅt¨ÙPÝ¨¦#ùˆÃ1L‡™
Ól:rh2n(" ±‰0ÀÀ(%!55-5%)5©(©8©0µ(µ £0#-#=#©©µ##
5Æ,1y= j–%†$==†$%%«=9%p@²H(±¨è1Äè±d(¡G3›œƒA•"
string(212) "‹c22Ñ5±RÈM-ÉÈOÉLNÌQpdFZ6<€Ÿ,Ðe×q¢‹s¡Ò@3!<˜¸­DŽÅt¨ÙPÝ¨¦#ùˆÃ1L‡™
Ól:rh2n(" ±‰0ÀÀ(%!55-5%)5©(©8©0µ(µ £0#-#=#©©µ##
5Æ,1y= j–%†$==†$%%«=9%p@²H(±¨è1Äè±d(¡G3›œƒA•ˆÉl–U"
string(200) "xœc22Ñ5±RÈM-ÉÈOÉLNÌQpdFZ6<€Ÿ,Ðe×q¢‹s¡Ò@3!<˜¸­DŽÅt¨ÙPÝ¨¦#ùˆÃ1L‡™
Ól:rh2n(" ±‰0ÀÀ(%!55-5%)5©(©8©0µ(µ £0#-#=#©©µ##
5Æ,1y= j–%†$==†$%%«=9%p@²H(±¨è1Äè±d(¡G3›œƒA•)¥]"
```

So *none* of the options actually return the original. How do I reverse php's `zlib_decode()`?

---

**Edit**

This is the data I start with:

```
eNpjEDIy0TWxUshNLcnIT8lMTsxRcGQAAkZaAjYGPICdkQEvYIS4jhNdnAMoCJUGmsEI4cH0wG0lwnAspkPNhupGNR3JR8QYjmE6zGyYbmTTkUOLkOGcyAZCATaxEQYYGKXEgAEgpKampaYkpSYVJRUnFaYWpRZkFGakZaRnpCIVIxWhFmKkY6ShxsCYJSavB1TNkqDEkKQno8eQpKSgxOBglaLHIKcEDkgWCSUWFT2GGD2WDCX0KGBmk3MwqJJjYAAAKaUWXQ==
```

I decode that with php's `base64_decode`, after which I get the first string in the post.

Comment: Probably want to reverse the encode/decode functions. You are trying to decode first and then encode again. That output looks similar to what the encoded data should look like.

Comment: That's exactly the point. I'm trying to reverse another compression function I wrote but this is where it's going wrong. The question is, how do I properly reverse `zlib_decode()`?

Comment: zlib decode should give you decoded data. To compress, encode, decompress, decode. If you are using decode in the other function, you likely want encode there and are trying to decode invalid data, returning null. Your encode function should be something like `zlib_encode(base64_encode($string))` and to reverse would be `base64_decode(zlib_decode($codedData));`

Comment: This should always work, so the problem is during encoding, not decoding. You didn't share the code where you originally encode the data.

Comment: I'm not encoding the data. I get the encoded data, and decompress it. Now I wish to reverse that action.

Comment: From what you were saying above though, the data you get isn't encoded.  It is a `base64_encoded` string that is passed to decode, not encode. `zlib_decode` should return the string originally encoded, not the other way around. This is why it would be good to post the original encoding function. So we could actually help instead of just guessing.

Comment: Right. But by "the data is first base-64 encoded and then zlib-encoded" I just meant to state the format of the data. I'm retrieving the original, decoded string by decoding it, I don't know what the data represents beforehand

Comment: If you first base-64 encode and the zlib encode, the opposite would be zlib decode then base-64 decode.

Comment: I know that. That's what I'm doing. I base64 decode, and look what it outputs (let's call this the *cool data*). Then I do zlib_decode, with which I decoded the data. Now a step back would be zlib_encode, but that doesn't output the *cool data* like it should. The *cool data* would have to be base64 encoded, too, to achieve the final result, but this is where it goes wrong.

Comment: I did `zlib_decode(base64_decode($data))` where `$data` is your original string as shown at the bottom of the question.  My PHP shows: ``"24-4: methodical A&&*&"&Z^V&Z&R2V2*2.2$\X&T2,2(&j.`"b..b" "@:d.""$.\.h"@0z``.

Comment: That is correct. The rest of the function decodes the other symbols, but I won't bother you with that for it has nothing to do with the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The guarantee of the lossless compressor is that `zlib_decode(zlib_encode(original_data))` will always return `original_data`.

However there is no guarantee that `zlib_encode(zlib_decode(compressed_data))` will return `compressed_data`. The `compressed_data` you are providing could have been compressed at a different compression level, with a different compression strategy, with a different algorithm, or even simply with a different version of the same compression code. There are an infinite number of compressed representations of the same source data and there is no requirement on the compressor to produce a particular one out of that infinite set.

There is not even a requirement that a compressor be deterministic, so long as the lossless guarantee is met. However most compression codes that you will meet are deterministic. So while not guaranteed, it is quite likely that `zlib_encode(original_data)` will always return the same result when run with the same input, the same version and build of `zlib_encode()`, and the same options.

Now for a slight diversion into history. Early versions of zlib's deflate were not deterministic, since the result could depend on the contents of uninitialized memory. Even though that deflate code would always produce a correct result and would always satisfy the lossless guarantee, the non-determinism bothered folk. So that was later fixed to make deflate deterministic.

By the way, why do you care? Why would there be a need to replicate the same compressed data (which you know you could just copy, right?), so long as you are assured that you will get the original data when you decompress?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The reason I care, is so that I can change the data and upload that, but I already got stuck at *not* changing it and uploading it.

Answer (score 2):

If you encode twice you should use the reverse order to decode.

So:

```
$data = base64_encode($data);
$data = zlib_encode($data);
```

to encode and to decode:

```
$data = zlib_decode($data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
```

I'm not sure, but you seem to get this order wrong?

Comment: Right, I stated it wrong - I edited my post. A bit silly of me. But, that doesn't change anything about the problem that arose...

Comment: Oh, oke, that can happen. Your strings contain a lot of 'strange' characters, basically you shouldn't treat them as strings of characters also called 'text', but as an array of bytes. Hold on, I'm getting to the point. Text has it's own problems with encoding when you transfer it from one place to another, for instance form a database to a webpage. UTF-8 to Latin-1, etc. Make sure you treat encoded stuff as bytes, not as characters.

Comment: Okay! That clears things up. However, `zlib_decode()` will return a string, so how would I be sure to treat them as bytearray? I suppose the damage has already been done after the `zlib_decode`, am I right?

Comment: No, it's what you do with the string that can do the damage: converting it from one encoding to another without you being aware of it. For instance if your database uses Latin-1, but your source uses UTF-8, the string will be converted, or misinterpreted if you store it as `TEXT`. In that case you will have to use `BLOB` or `VARBINARY` in the database. Etc. Such a conversion can have many causes. I'm not saying your problem is due to this, but it is not unlikely.